# How to extract middle values in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract the fifth and sixth value present in the stream through regex.

The stream is

```cs
12,097.00 435.00 100.00 43,037.00 3,090.00 200.00 86.00 45,890.47 7,570.00 51,514.47
```

I want values `200.00` and `100.00`.

I tried `^(?:\S+\s+\n?){3,3}` but it's selecting the string from beginning.

Can anybody help me please in getting the values that are present in the middle?

Comment: I think splitting and selecting the desired values is a better solution here than regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a quantifier like `{3,3}` can be written as `{3}`, but note that in the example string the values `200.00` and `100.00` are not the 5th and the `6th` value.

With your pattern you only get the values at the beginning as the anchor `^` asserts the start of the string.

To get the third and the sixth value, you could also use 2 capture groups by using a quantifier `{2}` for the parts in between.

```
^(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+)(?:\s+\S+){2}\s+(\S+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\S+\s+){2}` Repeat 2 times matching non whitespace chars followed by whitespace char
- `(\S+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+\S+){2}\s+` Repeat 2 times matching whitespace chars and non whitespace chars
- `(\S+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9dXaxx/1)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, if you have access to the code itself, it would be easier to split the string and get nth chunk by its index.

If you are limited to a regex, you can use

```cs
(?<=^(?:\S+\s+){2})\S+
(?<=^(?:\S+\s+){5})\S+
```

Or, if there can be leading whitespaces:

```cs
(?<=^\s*(?:\S+\s+){2})\S+
(?<=^\s*(?:\S+\s+){5})\S+
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%28%3F%3A%5CS%2B%5Cs%2B%29%7B2%7D%29%5CS%2B&i=12%2C097.00%20435.00%20100.00%2043%2C037.00%203%2C090.00%20200.00%2086.00%2045%2C890.47%207%2C570.00%2051%2C514.47).

*Details*:

- `(?<=` - start of a positive lookbehind that requires the following sequence of patterns to appear immediately to the left of the current location:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:\S+\s+){2}` - two occurrences of 1+ non-whitespace chars followed with 1+ whitespace chars
- `)` - end of the lookbehind
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.